# Rust: cannot move out of borrowed content

Tags: json, компиляция, rust

Задача: Распарсить Json структуру со вложенными данными. 
Код:

```
extern crate serde_json;
extern crate serde; 
extern crate serde_derive;

use serde_json::Value as JsonValue;

pub fn json_config(data: &str) {
    let mut fname: JsonValue; 
    let p = serde_json::from_str(data);
    let v: JsonValue = p.unwrap(); 

    fname = v["map"]["name"]; 
    println!("{:?}", fname);
}
```

**Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1ed0e24a6d881eb609bf2b5b4b8b5bf9**

Лог ошибки:

```
warning: variable does not need to be mutable
 --> src/lib.rs:8:9
  |
8 |     let mut fname: JsonValue; 
  |         ----^^^^^
  |         |
  |         help: remove this `mut`
  |
  = note: #[warn(unused_mut)] on by default

error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:12:13
   |
12 |     fname = v["map"]["name"]; 
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content

error[E0507]: cannot move out of data in a `&` reference
  --> src/lib.rs:12:13
   |
12 |     fname = v["map"]["name"]; 
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |             |
   |             cannot move out of data in a `&` reference
```

Искал в гугле, но все примеры идут со структурами, а у меня структур нету, и поэтому(допустим) `#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug, Copy, Clone)]` мне не поможет. 
Не понимаю почему так получается, не знаю что делать :(

Comment: В Расте не-[Copy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) типы (к которым относится JsonValue) по умолчанию перемещаются. Т.е. надо или взять ссылку (`let fname: &JsonValue = &v["map"]["name"];`), или [склонировать](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) значение (`let fname: JsonValue = v["map"]["name"].clone();`).

Comment: @ozkriff спасибо, понял!

Comment: Тип не обязательно указывать при введении переменной. Обычно компилятор может получить его из контекста.